# Plugin for tips on startup screen

Tags: plugin

Many of the IDEs I've tested throughout the years feature a sort of startup dialog, showing beginner to intermediate tips to become more proficient at it.

While ways to customize Vim startup screen exist--such as [vim-startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify), to name only one--I am not aware of any plugins that show usage tips on startup. Do these plugins exist?

Vim has a huge corpus of shortcuts, commands and configuration options, making it a daunting challenge to learn it all. With such a plugin, I think, it would be easier to learn something new every day.

Comment: You would need a source for the tips; after that I would imagine the rest is easy :) OTOH, consider reading parts of `:help` in order each day. You’ll learn quite a lot.